# Apex Generation Failed Unable to find element for {http://tempuri.org/}Get3DAssemblyFile_STLResponse

Tags: wsdl, wsdl2apex

I am getting this error while generating wsdl file.
Can any one help me to fix this error.
My wsdl :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://geometry.etoedge.com/GeometryService/Service.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" /> 
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://geometry.etoedge.com/GeometryService/Service.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"/> 
    <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://geometry.etoedge.com/GeometryService/Service.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/" />

</xsd:schema>-->

<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/"></xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"></xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/"></xsd:schema>
<!--<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/IGeometryDataService/Get3DAssemblyFile_STLResponse"></xsd:schema>-->
```

Comment: As you've noticed the Apex generation tooling from WSDL is pretty limited. You can't just comment out the imports, you have to manually gather the imported files and include them in your WSDL.

Comment: I have comment xsd:import because it don't support in wsdl generation I have converted them to xsd:schema if you see xsd:schema it is same as xsd:import .

Comment: I search for a definition of `Get3DAssemblyFile_STLResponse` and didn't find it; did you miss an import?

Comment: Sorry i think i missed in mu question. No i did not import because its url is http://tempuri.org/IGeometryDataService/Get3DAssemblyFile_STLResponse and iam already importing http://tempuri.org/. Do you think I need to import  http://tempuri.org/IGeometryDataService/Get3DAssemblyFile_STLResponse

Comment: You need to change references to **all** the external import files to copies of the content of those files embedded in the one WSDL file.

Comment: You mean I need to import this file to tempuri.org/IGeometryDataService/Get3DAssemblyFile_STLResponse right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25598/discussion-between-anu-and-keith-c).

Comment: Anu this is something you need to research yourself - this is a Q&A site not on online teaching site.

Answer (score 1):

The web service you are referencing (http://geometry.etoedge.com/GeometryService/Service.svc) has all the signs of being based on .NET.

When you ask for the WDSL, you have two options:

- http://geometry.etoedge.com/GeometryService/Service.svc?wsdl
- http://geometry.etoedge.com/GeometryService/Service.svc?singleWsdl

The former is the older way that .NET generated WSDLs. It is technically correct, but the native version of Wsdl2Apex doesn't support xsd:import.

The singleWsdl version will flatten this all down to a single WSDL that Wsdl2Apex will most likely support.